# Problem with events and ParseControl

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-controls, parsecontrol

I'm adding a control (linkbutton) dynamically using ParseControl and it's fine except when I specify an event handler.

If I use:

```
Dim c As Control = ParseControl("<asp:LinkButton id=""btnHide"" runat=""server"" text=""Hide"" OnClick="btnHide_Click" />")
```

it correctly adds the control to the page but the click event doesn't fire. If instead I find the control in the controls collection and manually wire up the event it works fine. I've tried loading in both Page_Init and Page_Load and it's the same thing either way.

Any ideas?

Edit:

In reality I'm not only parsing a single linkbutton in the code, I'm parsing a bunch of text that includes linkbuttons, checkboxes etc. I wonder if that has any bearing on it not performing as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:

```
Dim c As LinkButton = ParseControl("<asp:LinkButton id=""btnHide"" runat=""server"" text=""Hide""  />")
AddHandler c.Click, AddressOf btnHide_Click
```

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that I can do that if I need to but I just wanted to get to the bottom of why it doesn't work the other way. I'd like to simplify it as much as possible. One other thing I didn't mention is that I'm not just parsing a single linkbutton, I'm parsing a bunch of code to create multiple buttons in the same ParseControl statement.